# ListView onScroll causes SocketException

Tags: android, listview, socketexception

My ListView gets data from a web server.

Initially 10 items will be fetched and later onScroll 10 more and so on.

This works fine for 4-5 scrolls but later gives this Exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed.
```

after this:

```
E/OSNetworkSystem(27034): JNI EX in read
```

and sometimes instead of **Socket closed**, even this Exception occurs:

```
java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream
```

and then instead of adding 10 new items, it adds 10 previously fetched items. This is because I'm not replacing the items in the ArrayList used in the Adapter, because of the Exception.

What causes this Exception?

**EDIT:**

It works fine for first 3-5 scrolls, then gives me some wrong data (previous data) because of this Exception and if I continue scrolling, it works fine later and again gives the Exception later, randomly.

**Code to fetch list items:**

*postData to get data from the web server*

```
public static String PostData(String url, String sa[][]) {

        DefaultHttpClient client = getThreadSafeClient();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        int n = sa.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(sa[i][0], sa[i][1]));
            Log.d(sa[i][0], "" + sa[i][1]);
        }
        HttpPost httppost;
        try {
            httppost = new HttpPost(baseUrl + url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try {
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
            String line = "0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append("\n" + line);
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*ThreadSafeClient i am using in PostData*

```
    public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
    return client;
}
```

*AsyncTask in my Activity to get new Data onScroll. This is called in onScroll*

```
AsyncTask{

ArrayList<item> itemList = new Arraylist<item>();
doInBackground(){

    String response = PostData(url, sa);
    //sa has namevaluepairs as a 2-dimensional array
    JSONArray JArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++){

        itemList.add(convertToItem(JArrya.getJSONObject("items")));
    }
}
onPostExecute(){

    for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
        mListAdapter.add(itemList.get(i));
    }
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

*Its a long code, so pasting just the important lines*

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After changing the **PostData** method to this, it worked fine.

```
public static String PostData(String url, String sa[][]) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    int n = sa.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(sa[i][0], sa[i][1]));
    }
    HttpPost httppost;
    httppost = new HttpPost(baseUrl + url);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = null;
    response = client.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String res = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    return res;
}
```

So, is it because **is(InputStream)** and **sb(Stringbuilder)** are not **Local Variables** in the previous case?

Thank You

Comment: Socket exception is generally dude to improper network connectivity

Comment: if your mobile's internet connection gets disconnected this exception is thrown, this is not the only reason, this may be one of the reason.

Comment: You should elaborate on your network code, what it does and how it is invoked in relation to list scrolling as this is where the error likely lies.

Comment: @Guykun yeah done.I have added all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `PostData()` isn't thread safe because you are using two objects not defined in the method:

```
is = entity.getContent();
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

This results in the sockect from other running thread to be closed by:

```
is.close();
```

Define both of them locally to the method and it should solve the issue.

Regards.

Comment: can you please check the last edit and confirm on that? Thank you

Comment: Yes. It looks like that these local variables were the problem. You started using the local object method to achive the same objective and the problem is solved. To build a thread safe code, you can't use global objects without `synchronized()` block, for the simple reason that after one thread set the object value, it can be interrupted and another thread starts. The value in that object will then be used/re-writen in the other thread causing the issue.

Comment: Just one more comment. SDK prior to `DONUT` and equal or newer then `HONEYCOMB` only allows one `AsyncTask` at a time. If you want the same behaviour (several fecths in parallel) on all devices you need to use `Thread` class (or other class providing threads).

Comment: Be aware that newer Android versions `HONEYCOMB +` reverte again to single thread pool in `AsyncTask`. That means only one asynctask running at a time again. See `Order of Execution`in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Answer (score 1):

On scroll is called every time your ListView's y coordinates have changed, so it might be, that you are making many connections to the server when your list is scrolled, which may cause the exception.

This might help you:
http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

Comment: But i have conditions in **onScroll** to make a connection **only if last item is reached** and the **ListView is not being populated by new data**